# Clickable picture array image output size - can't control dimensions of individual output pictures

Tags: javascript, image, output, image-size

I have a picture array of a sort that shows a large picture and some thumbnail pictures. The thumbnails each need to cause the larger picture (all the same picture) above them, but with the picture being a different size. All the forums seem to tell me not to do this, but I want to do so to not have to upload copies of the same photo (save time) as I have a few hundred parts diagrams I need to display this way. A link to where the code is posted is listed below. I'd post the code in this thread, but I'm new, so stackoverflow won't let me. I have changed the output photos slightly to show that the bottom button are actually doing something as well.

http://www.snoscoot.com/test3.html

Would anyone be able to tell me how to change the output image size? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can change an image's size by its `height` and `width` properties.  Note that this resizes the image, and can be subject to warping.

It is suggested that you resize a large image to smaller thumbnails, because it is extremely wasteful to request a huge image then to style it to be a small thumbnail image.  You can rather easily create a script that will resize images for you to an number and combination of sizes

Comment: Yes, I am aware that you can chance an image's height and width when displaying with a standard <img src=" ">, but that doesn't work with this code because it's not that simple of a format. I am trying to resize the output picture sizes (that picture that appears when you click on the small arrows). Do you know how to do that?